# how to restrict default ordering of Hash Set in java

Tags: java, collections, set

I have some of values in my java program. I just stored those values in `HashSet`. I have stored it by for loop. The values iterating by loop has been ordered differently after the set formed. How can restrict this order change of `HashSet` as I get from the loop. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the set to maintain the insertion order, you can use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which **is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)**.

Alternatively, if you want your set to be ordered, you can use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: Or a TreeSet if you want it to be ordered naturally.

Answer (score 5):

A `HashSet` is unordered, as the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) specify:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time. This class permits the null element.

You might want to consider using a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which maintains the order of insertions.

An alternative is using one of the [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) implementations, such as the [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which guarantee order according to the natural order or `Comparator`, if given.

Answer (score 3):

use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) predictable iteration order